# Hot Reload with Dockerized Node-Typescript application

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm dockerizing an api container and want it to be able to hot reload whenever I make change in code. I created a volume to handle it but nothing happen.

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  api:
    image: xinxo-api:latest
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - "5005:5005"
    networks:
      - xinxo-network
    volumes:
      - apibuild:/app/api/build
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    env_file:
      - ./api/.env
    restart: always
networks:
  xinxo-network:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  pgdata:
  cache:
  staticbuild:
  apibuild:
```

Here's my `Dockerfile`

```bash
FROM node:16-bullseye-slim

WORKDIR /app/api/build

COPY package*.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./
COPY ./prisma prisma

RUN yarn
RUN yarn prisma generate

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5005
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

I only have [a screen shot of my `package.json` file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYY5t.png).

Comment: I'd recommend just installing Node instead.  Don't bother with Docker here; instead, just run `yarn start` and it will use the files you have locally.

Comment: This project has some containers apart from api server: nginx, redis, nextjs.... And not all of my teammates can config the environment themselve then I've tried to use Docker

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a local are mounted as a volume into the running container. How are you updating the `apibuild` files?

Comment: I have checked volume of this api container, and saw that all of my codes have copied successfully. So is that satisfied ?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue already by changing 2 places:

1. docker-compose:
   volumes:

   - apibuild:/app/api/build -> ./api:/app/api/build
2. My start script in package.json

"start": "ts-node-dev --poll --respawn --transpile-only --exit-child    --no-notify --ignore-watch node_modules -r tsconfig-paths/register src/app.ts"